# Ajustar misma altura entradas/cajas en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

www.comprasychollos.es he añadido a entry-content height 340px

Y en el plugin de aawp que muestra foto, descripción, botón he cambiado:
display: contents;

En el ordenador se visualiza correctamente, pero en el móvil no aparecen todas las descripciones y botón de compra, además se sobrasale de los bordes pasado el footer en entradas del blog al tener bastante más texto.

El código de la hoja de estilos podrían ser estos parámetros los que tengo que modificar:

```
/* =Blog - Style 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.blog-style2 .blog-grid.column-2 {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.blog-style2 .blog-grid.column-3 { 
    width: 33%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.blog-style2 .blog-grid.column-4 { 
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.blog-style2 .blog-article {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.blog-style2 .blog-article .entry-content {
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;


----------
```

El problema también es al darle una altura específica el contenido en blog sobresale al tener demasiado texto.

https://abload.de/img/1yrksk.jpg

https://abload.de/img/2akjzm.jpg

https://abload.de/img/3vjk94.jpg

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando he conseguido solucionarlo gracias al plugin: Equal Height Columns

Especificando entry-content y asignándole 330px así no ha descuadrado las entradas de blog que contenían más texto y se visualiza perfecto en el móvil.